# Examples of Smooth Immersions

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to develop an intuition about the concept of an immersion in differential geometry.

> Let $\Psi : M \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be an injective, smooth immersion. Set M=(0,1)x(0,1) $\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

**1.** Example of $\Psi$, such that $\Psi(M)$ is closed and not contained in any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$: 
 
$\Psi(x,y) := (\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},0)$. Thus $\Psi(M)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and still an unbounded subset.

**2.** Example of $\Psi$, such that $\Psi(M)$ is not compact, but contained in a compact subset $K         \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. 
My assumption was to treat $\Psi(M)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ relative to the topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now I'm unsure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Your question is confusing: you write $\Psi : M \to \mathbb R^2$ but then you say that $\Psi(M)$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks, I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example in **1.** is indeed unbounded, but it is not closed: the point $(1,1,0)$ is the limit of the sequence of points 
$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n},\frac{n+1}{n},0 \right) = \Psi\left(\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n}{n+1}\right) \in \Psi(M)
$$
but $(1,1,0) \not\in \Psi(M)$.

Regarding **2,** I would simply suggest that you write down formulas for very simplest example of immersions, and then attempt to use the formula to prove the properties of $\Psi(M)$ that you are asked to prove.

Comment: About 1: Perhaps the approach of stretching the open unit square to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be better. For 2, I would additionally like the resulting boundary of $\Psi (M)$ to be disconnected, so it seems, that a simple inclusion won't do the job.